# MasterPage.Master > Which page will be next loaded as a child?

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest, master-pages, master-detail

I would like to know, in the `Page Load` event of my `MasterPage.Master` which page <del>sent the request.</del> will be loaded as child in the content.

Supposing, the user clicks in my webpage `<a href="Login.aspx">Login</a>` can i get that value from the `Page Load` event of my `MasterPage.Master` for later processing?

```
Dim ThePageThatWillLoadAsChildIs as string =
```

You see i would like to use that, so when the request page is e.x. Login.aspx, inject in the form element of my webpage some attributes.

Comment: I think there is a small missunderstanding here. Do you want the page where the link was clicked or the page which is being loaded right now? Referrer or Target?

Comment: @Elad Lachmi I need the target. The hyperlink <a href="Login.aspx">Login</a> actually exists on the MasterPage.Master

Comment: Then you need to use citronas` method. My answer was considering you want to know the source of the click, not the currently requested page. btw: This will work if the URLs are different. You might need to use query strings, if the request if for the same  physical aspx filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at Request.Url Property and get the necessary information there

Comment: @Chocol8: My answer tells you how to access the current browsed page

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is Request.UrlReferrer

Answer (score 0):

Well this one does the trick (On the master page load)

```
Private Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
   Dim TheNextPageThatWillLoad As String = DirectCast(sender, MasterPage).Request.RawUrl
End Sub
```